# How to ignore pojo annotations while using Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've a POJO with Jackson annotations

```
     public class Sample{

        private String property1;

        @JsonIgnore
        private String property2;

        //...setters getters

     }
```

So, when Jackson library is used for automarshalling by other frameworks such as RestEasy these annotations help guide the serialization and deserilization process.

But when I want to explicitly serialize using ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(), I don't want those annotations to make any effect, instead I will configure the mapper object to my requirement.

So, how to make the annotations not make any effect while using ObjectMapper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Configure your `ObjectMapper` not to use those Annotations, like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(
                 org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)
                    .configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);
```

This works!

Comment: When I wrote this, I got `The method configure(MapperFeature, boolean) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (DeserializationConfig.Feature, boolean)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MahmoudMubarak This answer is for codehaus version  of jackson. See above answer if you are using fasterxml?

Answer (score 24):

Hi if you are using **com.fasterxml.jackson** then code is -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
```

Comment: or mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);